# How to filter request parameters in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a form which submits 3 request parameters: name, age, location.

This method gets both parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void displayData(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters, HttpServletResponse response)
{
}
```

How can I configure the `@RequestParam` do get only the name and location values and put them in a Map ?

I need to filter some of the request parameters. Should I filter them using `@RequestParam` or should I filter them in the method implementation ?

I know there is `@RequestParam( value = "name" )` and should work in this case, but what is the elegant and right approach if you have 20 different parameters and you only one to get 5 of them from the request?

Since I am new to `Spring MVC` and help is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with the [`params` attribute of `@RequestMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29)? For instance:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "name", "age", "location" })
public void displayData(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters, HttpServletResponse response)
{
}
```

Does it correspond to what you expect?